# Hosting 2 applications on 2 different sub-domains In IIS

Tags: windows, iis, hosting, web-hosting, iis-8

I have 2 applications A and B and have 2 subdomain's for them - a.xyz.com and b.xyz.com. Now a is running on port 80 and mapped to a.xyz.com subdomain but when I am trying the same for b I am getting an error that "other Website is already using port 80"

Can any one please help me on how I can map application b which is locally working on port 7000 to b.xyz.com?

I have tried to bind the application b to hostname b.xyx.com and port 7000 but that is redirecting it to b.xyz.com:7000. But I don't want subdomain with any IP.

I am new to IIS hosting so if I am making a mistake please let me that as well.

Comment: You just need to learn what site bindings are, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Answer (score 0):

This is by design.

When you have to share port 80 for two different sites, then you have to specify IP address for at least one binding host header. Otherwise, you can't get both sites with 80 port start side by side.

Please modify one application or both's binding to xxx.xxx.xxx:80:subdomain.xyz.com. It is impossible to share 80 port without setting IP address in binding host header.